# Missing PayPal IPN notification

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

On our website we have option to pay using PayPal. At the time of signup our sytem creates recurring profile in users PayPal account and then till the account continue we receive recurring Payments.

On every successful payment PayPal send us the notifications with transaction details and we updates our system. 
Sometimes our system miss the IPN notifications due to outage and as a result our system goes out of sync and does not updates the payments.

I would like to know do we have any PayPal API which we can call to get the transaction details of missing IPN notifications?

How to handle these transactions which are not updated in our system and IPN we ave missed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, but the account holder can view sent IPNs and resend failed ones via the Web browser interface.

Comment: Hi EJP, In the IPN history logs it is saying notification sent successfully but in our system on the very first line I am recording all requests into DB then processing it, And I am not getting any log in our DB so it means we have not received that notifications. I would like to know the cause or any other way to handle it so that our system does not miss any transaction.